# Line separator not coming after div but at the topmost | CSS

Tags: html, css

I've made a div for header and other for putting a line separator after it. But line separator is not coming after but instead before the header. I've tried changing position too. (line separator width is done 10px and green for debugging. See image below).

**Output**
[image: line separator]

**header.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header-logo">FootGoal</div>
        <div id="header-nav">Account</div>
        <div id="header-bottom-line"></div>
    </div>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
body{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-right: 18%;
/*  overflow-y: scroll; */
/*  overflow-x: auto; */
}

#header{
    position: inherit; 
    display: block; 
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    width: 100%;    
}

#header-logo{
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(111,111,111);
}

#header-nav{ 
    position: relative;
    float: right; 
    padding-top: 12px; 
    padding-bottom: 2px; 
    padding-left: 12px; 
    padding-right: 12px; 
    font-size: 35px;
    height: 30px;
    color: blue;
}

#header-bottom-line{
    position: static;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;

}
```

Comment: you're floating your elements. Look up 'clear fix'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `overflow:auto` to the `#header-bottom-line` css.

Example:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-right: 18%;
  /*  overflow-y: scroll; */
  /*  overflow-x: auto; */
}
#header {
  position: inherit;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
#header-logo {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(111, 111, 111);
}
#header-nav {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  color: blue;
}
#header-bottom-line {
  position: static;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <f:view>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="header-logo">FootGoal</div>
      <div id="header-nav">Account</div>
      <div id="header-bottom-line"></div>
    </div>
  </f:view>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, I tidied everything up. Let me know if you have any questions about the code.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYMbej

THE CSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0 18% 0;
}

#header{
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.header-inner {
  overflow: auto;
}

#header-logo{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(111,111,111);
}

#header-nav{ 
  float: right; 
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  color: blue;
}

#header-bottom-line{
    height: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

THE HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
      <div class="header-inner">
        <div id="header-logo">FootGoal</div>
        <div id="header-nav">Account</div>
      </div>
      <div id="header-bottom-line"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up to better version.

Answer (score 0):

just need to add to the `#header-bottom-line` `clear:both`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cqvwz77y/)